# ElasticsearchRepository dynamic indexName

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In my project I am using ElasticsearchRepository, when my class is extending the ElasticsearchRepository.

Is there a way to change indexName property dynamically, I don't want to use @Document, since my indexName is dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

The @Document(indexName = "xxx") can be a SpEL expression. The expression is parsed whenever the index name is needed by SDE to obtain the index name. So, you could make the name be based on something you configure at runtime, via the application.yml file for example. In theory, anything you can do in SpEL should be possible.

I'm using it to define a "prefix" value that is prependded to all the index names to allow me to run multiple applications with the same base index names in the same ES cluster without clashing with each other. So I have my @Document() tag as:

```
@Document(indexName = "#{environment.getRequiredProperty('es.prefix') + '-doc'}")
```

And then I configure the es.prefix to be the value I want in the application.properties or application.yml file.

Comment: awesome! I tried on my own to it like that: 
`@Document(indexName="${spring.profiles.active}-dev")` as I do it in my controller namespaces but didn't work.